# Create new dataframe columns based on lists of indices in a column and another dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

Given the following dataframe and list of dictionaries:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([
                        {'id': '912SAFD', 'key': 3, 'list_index': [0]},
                        {'id': '812SAFD', 'key': 4, 'list_index': [0, 1]},
                        {'id': '712SAFD', 'key': 5, 'list_index': [2]}])

designs = [{'designs': [{'color_id': 609090, 'value': 'b', 'lang': ''}]}, 
           {'designs': [{'color_id': 609091, 'value': 'c', 'lang': ''}]}, 
           {'designs': [{'color_id': 609092, 'value': 'd', 'lang': 'fr'}]}]
```

Dataframe output:

```
        id  key list_index
0  912SAFD    3        [0]
1  812SAFD    4     [0, 1]
2  712SAFD    5        [2]
```

Without using explicit loops (if possible), is it feasible to iterate through the lists in `'list_index'` for each row, extract the values and use them to access the list of dictionaries by index and then create new columns based on the values in the dictionaries?

Here is an example of the expected result:

```
        id  key list_index 609090 609091 609092 609092_lang
0  912SAFD    3        [0]      b    NaN    NaN         NaN
1  812SAFD    4     [0, 1]      b      c    NaN         NaN
2  712SAFD    5        [2]    NaN    NaN      d          fr
```

If `'lang'` is not empty, it should be added as a column to the dataframe by using the `color_id` value combined with an underscore and its own name as the column name. For example: `609092_lang`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# this is to get the inner dictionary and make a tidy dataframe from it
designs = [info for design in designs for info in design['designs']]
df_designs = pd.DataFrame(designs)
df_designs['lang_code'] = 'lang_' + df_designs['color_id'].astype(str)
df_designs['lang'] = df_designs.lang.replace('', np.NaN)

df = df.explode('list_index').merge(df_designs, left_on='list_index', right_index=True)

df_color = df.pivot(index=['id', 'key'], columns=['color_id'], values='value')
df_lang = df.pivot(index=['id', 'key'], columns=['lang_code'], values='lang')
df = df_color.join(df_lang).reset_index().dropna(how='all' , axis=1)
print(df)
```

output :

```
>>>
        id  key 609090 609091 609092 lang_609092
0  712SAFD    5    NaN    NaN      d          fr
1  812SAFD    4      b      c    NaN         NaN
2  912SAFD    3      b    NaN    NaN         NaN
```

---

alternatively, if you could work with multiIndex df , instead of naming them, that would be simpler :

```
# this is to get the inner dictionary and make a tidy dataframe from it
designs = [info for design in designs for info in design['designs']]

df_designs = pd.DataFrame(designs)
df_designs['lang'] = df_designs.lang.replace('',np.NaN)

df = df.explode('list_index').merge(df_designs, left_on='list_index', right_index=True)
df = df.pivot(index=['id', 'key'], columns=['color_id'], values=['value','lang']).dropna(how='all' , axis=1).reset_index()
print(df)
```

output:

```
>>>
               id key  value                 lang
color_id              609090 609091 609092 609092
0         712SAFD   5    NaN    NaN      d     fr
1         812SAFD   4      b      c    NaN    NaN
2         912SAFD   3      b    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! Looks good..just `lang` should be actually `609092_lang`. Any ideas?

Comment: @DeepLearningEel hmm... let me think ... missed that part

Comment: @DeepLearningEel see updated answer,

Comment: @DeepLearningEel still this code should works ok.

Comment: And the `list_index` column disappears in the end? Can't I keep it